# URL rewrite in localhost IIS not working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, localhost, web-config

I have set up a localhost IIS server to test things. I can't seem to get the URL rewrite to work.

This is my pattern: `^image/([0-9]+)`

And this is the rewritten URL: `cache/images/{R:1}.jpg`

This should mean `http://127.0.0.1:2369/image/6`

Will go to `http://127.0.0.1:2369/cache/images/6.jpg`

Right?

Now when I go to the first link in my browser, somehow it goes to the index page...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using web.config instead of htaccess?

Comment: Oops, edited. I am using web.config. Actually, I'm using the UI from IIS manager, but it should be editing the web.config under the hood.